# i want execute arecord command in crontabe when my raspberry pi rebooting

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi

i want to run following command when my raspberry pi reboot.

```
arecord -fS16_LE -r 48000 -Dplughw:0,0 - | sudo Desktop/pifm/./pifm - 104.1 48000
```

please tell me how to do this job .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [raspberrypi.se]

Comment: Add that line to `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: wer should i add this line

Comment: can u tell correct line which i need to enter in crontab?